# VBA: insert max formula, referencing column of a closed workbook

Tags: vba, excel, max, formulas

First Post. I have a workbook that is a list of customer names, each name is a link to their individual workbook that is on a sharepoint site. The second column is a "Last contact" column which has a formula
    =MAX('https://example.com/folder/Folder/Customer Library/Area/T/[Customername.xlsm]Notes'!$B$2:$B$120)

I am able to make this formula manually by opening the linked workbook, selecting the cell on my customer list, enter "=max(" then highlight the range i want on the linked workbook. Works Fine.

Enter VBA because we want to simplify the procedure for adding customers to the list. I have a userform where you type in the customer name in a textbox1, and the address of the sharepoint wb in textbox 2. The submit button has the following code which inserts the customer name with a link to the sharepoint book in target cell of column A. This works fine. I also am trying to insert the MAX formula in the adjacent cell of column B. I can get the formula to the correct place. However, I am running into issues on the web reference, as it is textbox2's value. When I use textbox2.value it gives errors. Sorry for the book, here is the code without the web book reference:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Sheets("Dashboard").Select
NextFree = Range("A2:A" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row
Range("A" & NextFree).Select
ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), Address:=TextBox2.Value, TextToDisplay:=TextBox1.Value
Range("B" & NextFree).Formula = "=MAX(Notes'!$B$2:$B$120)"
UserForm1.Hide

Unload Me

End Sub
```

Between =Max( & Notes'... I know there needs to be textbox2 value, but I don't understand the syntax I suppose. The "Notes" is the sheet where the range is on the sharepoint wb. The range is the same for all additions to the customer list. Thank you for your help.

Update: I am now trying this code but get error Type Mismatch.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Sheets("Dashboard").Select
Dim SPbook As Workbook
Dim SPsheet As Worksheet
Dim SPrange As Range
Set SPbook = Workbooks.Open(TextBox2.Value)
Set SPsheet = Sheets("Notes")
Set SPrange = SPsheet.Range("B1:B120")
NextFree = Range("A2:A" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row
Range("A" & NextFree).Select
ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), Address:=TextBox2.Value, TextToDisplay:=TextBox1.Value
Range("B" & NextFree).Formula = "=MAX([" & SPrange & "])"
UserForm1.Hide

Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: have you tried `me.textbox2.value`? to troubleshoot, you can set a temporary variable: `aaa=me.textbox2.value`  and then `Range("B" & NextFree).Formula = aaa`.

Comment: I did per your suggestion, I am getting subscript out of range.

Answer (score 0):

You should reference `textbox2.Value` as follows:

```
Range("B" & NextFree).Formula = "=MAX(" & textbox2.Value $ "Notes'!$B$2:$B$120)"
```

Formula field takes a string so you just have to build the string concatenating your values.

If textbox2.Value is giving you an error this would not resolve this. Please include more details of this error including complete error message and what values are being passed to subroutine from the form. Regards,

Comment: Thanks for your response. I adjusted the code per your comment and received "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error. the debug highlights the line we just adjusted.

Comment: It is passing on the customer name and link to the page just fine, but the formula that should be in column B is blank

Comment: When it enters debug if you hover over `textbox2.Value` does it show a value? Can you try hardcoding the file address into the script just to see what results you get?